# Generate list of all valid BBCode entities for documentation reasons

Tags: php, documentation-generation, bbcode

I've managed to successfully integrate BBCode, but I was wondering say if I wanted to dynamically list all the allowed/accepted BBCode - how would I be able to do that? (as it can be tedious manually writing out...and if the BBCode ever changed I'd have to update the writing)

I current have a BBCode() function, which contains 2 arrays, one which contains the regex, and the other which contains the replacements (HTML), and then I return a `preg_replace()` of the regex array with the replacement (HTML) array.

Comment: Don't use BBCode - it sucks! There is so many other, userfriendly formats (Markdown for instance).

Comment: Crozin, I agree, but do you have any links to some tutorials and or information on alternatives?

Comment: http://xbeta.org/wiki/show/Markdown  SO uses it too: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a different markup language like Textile or Markdown. Simply saying that you support Markdown or Textile is decent enough; they're so widely used that users could easily look up the markup for them online.

Textile's syntax hasn't been updated since 2006, so it will likely remain very solid for years to come. Markdown's syntax hasn't been updated since 2004.

Both provide excellent PHP libraries:

- http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/
- http://textile.thresholdstate.com/